# package jar only some third party jars in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I am writing an app in businessobjects sdk and I need to develop it with like 8 million businessobjects jars brought into the build path.

I need one jar - opencsv - that will not be in the businessobjects platform build path when I run the app, so I think I should package this jar with my runnable jar for sure. The other businessobjects jars I do not need to package with my jar, BOE is already configured with them in the build path when I run the app from BOE .

However, do I need to package ALL the jars?  I only want one third party jar to go with my runnable jar.

Is there a way I can pick and choose which jars I pacakge with my runnable jar?

Comment: Do you really need an executable JAR? Can you use a POJ (Plain Old JAR)?

Comment: I'm not sure really.  I was told by someone who has done this a lot that I do need a runnable jar.  Someone else told me I dont need one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need a runnable JAR (ie, a "plain old" JAR), you can use Eclipse's export JAR wizard which allows you to specify exactly what files are included. You could easily include just the one library that you want that way, instead of relying on Eclipse to include every library (which is the normal expected behavior for a standalone runnable JAR).

Comment: Yeah I was aware of that actually.  I am just concerned witht he runnable jar right now